# Rails: collection based on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, routes

I had an index method that looked, awfully, like this:

```
  def index
    if params[:brand]
      @users = User.includes(:brand).where(brand_id: params[:brand]).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").page(params[:page]).per(10)
    elsif params[:search]
      @user = User.includes(:brand).find_by_client_code(params[:search])
      redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
    elsif params[:page] == 'all'
      @users = User.includes(:brand).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").all
    elsif params[:state]
      @users = User.includes(:brand).where(state: params[:state]).page(params[:page]).per(10)
    else
      @users = User.includes(:brand).order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}").page(params[:page]).per(10)
    end
  end
```

Pretty messy, I know, but it worked. Now I'm trying to refactor it and I can't figure out the best way to split it into smaller collections without complicating my routes.

```
  def index
    [:brand, :page, :search, :state].each do |param|
      if params[:page] == 'all'
        @users = User.includes(:brand).order(column + ' ' + direction)
      elsif params.key?(param)
        param
      else
        @users = User.includes(:brand).order(column + ' ' + direction)
                     .page(params[:page]).per(10)
      end
    end
  end

  def brand
    @users = User.includes(:brand).where('brand_id in (?)', params[:brand])
                 .order(column + ' ' + direction).page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def state
    @users = User.includes(:brand).where(state: params[:state])
                 .page(params[:page]).per(10)
  end

  def search
    @user = User.includes(:brand).find_by_client_code(params[:search])
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
  end
```

The above doesn't work but you get the idea. Anyone know a good way to deal with this type of situation? Cheers.

Comment: I just walked the same learning path. I used to put all my AJAX requests into the template's action but am now putting them in their own methods. I couldn't find a whole lot of guidance on the internet regarding this topic tbh. I hope someone more experienced will chime in but I separated most AJAX requests into their own actions and routes and am pleased with the results. The logic is easier to follow and my actions aren't cluttered. My routes file is more populated, but with proper organization it still looks clean. Good question!

Comment: Which version of ruby you are using?

Comment: I'm using Ruby `2.1.2`.

Comment: Also I don't see respond block here. Are you requesting this with HTML or js format?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, it's removed. HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry,  couldn't help myself to ask this. Aren't you confusing your index method with `@users ` and `@user `. It would be much easier to handle one instance than two in view. Just saying. Let's say just `@users `

Comment: I can split the plural collections from the singular, sure. But what of the others? Is separate routes just easier?

Comment: @emm Sorry, I didn't see that you're redirecting to edit user path for `@user` maybe because when I was reading the question it wasn't there before. However, have a look at the answer I've posted, it'll give you an idea how to go about doing something like this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do it this way -

First, update this code where you have defined `sort_column` and `sort_direction` methods to have default values:

```
def sort_column
  colum_name = params[:colum_name]
  colum_name ||= 'id'
end

def  sort_direction
  direction = params[:direction]
  direction ||= 'ASC'
end
```

Add a new method to have `per_page`(at the same place where you have `sort_column` and `sort_direction`) from params or default from `User` class:

```
def per_page
  per = params[:per_page]
  per ||= User.per_page
end
```

in *app/models/user.rb*:

```
scope :with_brand_id, ->(id) { where(brand_id: id) }
scope :with_state,    ->(state) { where(state: state) }
scope :order_with,    ->(column_name, direction) { order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}") }

# never use/avoid magic numbers in your application at multiple places as they gets unmanageable as your application grows
# single place to manage your per page entries for users.
def self.per_page
  10
end

# easy to use key:value based arguments since you're using Ruby 2, cheers!
def self.fetch_with_brand(brand: nil, state: nil, page: nil, sort_column: 'id', sort_direction: 'ASC', per_page: User.per_page)
  user_scope, pagination_scope_applies =  if brand.present?
    [self.with_brand_id(brand), true]
  elsif state.present?
    [self.with_state(state), true]
  else
    [self.scoped, (page != 'all')]
  end

  user_scope.merge(pagination_scope(page, per_page)) if pagination_scope_applies
  user_scope.includes(:brand).order_with(sort_column, sort_direction)
end

# since I am not sure about your implementation of `page` and `per` methods, I'd create a class method, otherwise you can create a `scope` for this, too
def self.pagination_scope(page_number, per_page)
  self.page(page_number).per(per_page)
end
```

Do you se the line: `[self.scoped, (page != 'all')]` in code mentioned above? Here `self.scoped` is equal to `self.all`(when evaluated), but we will have to use `scoped` instead of `all` as in Rails 3 it gives an **Array**, while in Rails 4 it will be an **ActiveRecord::Relation** object so you can use `self.all` if you're on Rails 4. NOTE: `scoped` is deprecated in Rails 4 in favor of `all`.

Also, I'd like to point out a gotcha here. In your code you're giving priority to `params[:page] == 'all'` condition and then to `params[:search]`. In the code I mentioned above gives priority to `search` and then to `page`, but you get the idea, right?

Now, let's add user specific params method in the controller:

```
def user_params
  params.slice(:brand, :page, :state).merge!({sort_column: sort_column, sort_direction: sort_direction, per_page: per_page })
end
```

However, in Rails 4 it is easier to do with strong parameters, e.g.: `params.require(:user).permit(:search,..)` etc.

Now, your controller's index method can look something like this:

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    @user = User.find_by_client_code(params[:search])
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
  else
    @users = User.fetch_with_brand(user_params)
  end
end
```

Or you can refactor it further if you tend to redirect user to edit page in more places:

```
before_filter :redirect_to_edit, only: [:index, :some_other_method_name]

def index
  @users = User.fetch_with_brand(user_params)
end

def redirect_to_edit
  if params[:search].present?
    @user = User.find_by_client_code(params[:search])
    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
  end
end
```

You have your **skinny controller** up now.